# Mass update 'View As' for Dashboards

Tags: dashboard, view

I would like to mass update the 'View As' user on a group of dashboards to a new general user. From the research I have done, someone had a similar question and suggested updating metadata. When looking into it I only found info on custom meta data, would this be the correct route to go?

*Note: I am not a developer, but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Hi Kate, welcome to the Salesforce StackExchange platform. Please provide more details about your researches and the outcomes. Maybe post a link to what you've already found online. This post helps you find out more details on how to ask a question in order to get the fastest and most accurate answers. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_dashboard.htm), it looks like the Dashboard object is read-only so you can't change it via the API.